# Ignoring exception in command None discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord music bot. I finished the code but I get this error all the time: :Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found
Please Help me ! Here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


TOKEN = 'token here'
intents = discord.Intents.all()


class MusicBot(commands.Bot):
    initial_extensions = ['cogs.playcommand']

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Music online!')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(f'Message from {message.author}: {message.content}')
        await self.process_commands(message)


##################################################

client = MusicBot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


async def load_extensions():
    for extension in client.initial_extensions:
        await client.load_extension()


client.run(TOKEN)
```

This is my main.py file.

And here's my cog:

```
import os

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl


class PlayCommand(commands.Cog):
    def __int__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name='play')
    async def play(self, ctx, url):
        voicec = ctx.author.voice
        if voicec:
            channel = voicec.channel
            if channel:
                songname = f'songs/{ctx.guild.id}_current.mp3'
                song_there = os.path.isfile(songname)
                try:
                    if song_there:
                        os.remove(songname)
                        print('Removed old song file')
                except PermissionError:
                    print('Trying to delte file , buit its beeing played')
                    await ctx.send('Error: Music playing')
                    return

                voice = await channel.connect()
                ydl_opts = {
                    'format': "bestaudio/best",
                    'postprocessors': [{
                        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                        'preferredquality': '192'
                    }]
                }

                with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                    print('Donwloading audio now\n')
                    ydl.download([url])

                for file in os.listdir('./'):
                    if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                        print(f'Renamed file: {file}\n')
                        os.rename(file, songname)

                voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(songname), after=lambda e: print('Song zu ende.'))
                voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)

                print('Ok.')

        #################################################


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(PlayCommand(bot))
```

I tried evrything on youtube but on youtbe there are videos of old version of discord.py , because in the new version you must await load_extension and await bot.add_Cog().

Comment: If you type / do you see your bot with the /play command?

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to the asyncio changes in discord.py v2.0, the loading and unloading of extensions and cogs is now asynchronous ([read more](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous)).
This way you will need to load the extensions in an async context as shown below:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio


TOKEN = 'token here'
intents = discord.Intents.all()


class MusicBot(commands.Bot):
    initial_extensions = ['cogs.playcommand']

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Music online!')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(f'Message from {message.author}: {message.content}')
        await self.process_commands(message)


##################################################

bot = MusicBot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

async def main():
    async with bot:
        for extension in bot.initial_extensions:
            await bot.load_extension()
        await bot.start(TOKEN)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks you really helped me ! But now T´I have a new issue , the bot joins the voice channel downloads the song and conevert it. But he doesn't play's it

Comment: I recommend that you create a new topic for this new issue